# declare ticks and register tick function gives infinite loop

Tags: php

Saw a similar question in SO with no answers.  Trying to learn ticks and the example in php.net keeps loading without any output.  Can anyone help shed some light as to why this can happen? PHP Version is 7.0.9.

```
<?php
   declare(ticks=1);
   function my_function(){
     echo 'Tick function called';
   }
   register_tick_function('my_function', true);
```

Comment: Works for me, I cannot find an issue.

Comment: Is this all of the code on the page or is there more to it?

Comment: Works for me too. As written, outputs `Tick function called`, so the problem is likely with something else.

Comment: the page contains nothing except this.  Clueless as to why this is happening.  If I comment either of delcare or register function line, the page stops this infite loading and outputs blank as expected.  If I comment the function, it shows errors as expected.  Warning: register_tick_function(): Invalid tick callback 'my_function' passed in E:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments stated the code works, I assumed and replaced php.ini file and this works perfectly.  Appreciate the quick help.  Hope this thread helps someone.